# Для каких задач Node.js является более приоритетным выбором среди других платформ?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Для каких задач и ситуаций Node.js является более приоритетным выбором среди других платформ?
Есть на вскидку:
- сборка фронта,
- бэк если занимается фуллстэк разработчик со знанием только js,
- задачи где требуется быстрый ввод/вывод (чаты (а что еще?))

Может что-то еще?
Есть ли задачи кроме фронтэнда и Node.js (может другие платформы), где требуется js в качестве скриптового языка?

Comment: Все серверы умеют делать плюс\минус одно и то же. Нельзя сказать, что вот Java больше подходит для таких зада, C# для других, а Node.js для третьих.

Comment: @stepan-kasyanenko разница как минимум в стоимости, скорости разработки, скорости ответа сервера, и т.п. (это если мы говорим про обычные crm'ы)

Comment: Да? А на чем дешевле сделать, на Java, JS или C#? Или на чем быстрее? Какой серверный язык быстрее? Все это очень относительно и зависит от компетенций команды, которая все это делает. Но уж никак не от самого стека.